# Spring Tools Suit 4 and Spring roo

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, spring-tools-4

I cannot create Spring Roo project is Spring tools Suit 4.  Do I need to install a plugin?  I tried to install Spring Roo plugin from Eclipse market place but no user. Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Roo integration from Spring IDE is not part of the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution. It still comes as part of the Spring Tool Suite 3 for Eclipse, which can be downloaded from https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all, but it is not in active development anymore and receives minimal maintenance only.